# Presentation mode for Google Colab notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, reveal.js, google-colaboratory

Is there Presentation Mode (like Jupyter RISE) for Google Colab notebooks in the browser? I could not find anything in documentation, FAQ and issue tracker.

https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools

https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html

https://github.com/damianavila/RISE

Comment: I doubt it since RISE is an nbextension designed for notebooks.  I must be possible.

Comment: It should be possible. I remember there are some other nbextensions usable on Colab before somewhere.

Comment: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/346

Comment: The actual github issue is here: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/241

Answer (score 9):

There is no presentation mode. They should implement one though, so keep using what you are using.